# Rotate table view in Oracle without aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table of the following form:

```
Date  | Value  
01/01 |    10  
01/02 |    11  
01/03 |    12
```

and so on for distinct dates of a month. I need to rotate this view and show all the dates as columns and corresponding values underneath each of the dates as column headers. The idea is to join such a rotated table against a reference table:

```
Product ID | Name  
A123       | Axle  
B234       | Bearing
```

and repeat across all the rows something like:

```
Product ID | Name    | 01/01 | 01/02 | ... | 01/31  
A123       | Axle    |    10 |    11 | ... |   100  
B234       | Bearing |    10 |    11 | ... |   100
```

The values above 10,11,..etc, can be static as in the first table of dates above. Suggestions? I tried using pivot but I do not want an aggregation.

Comment: the number of dates appears to be N (unknown unlimited).  Which means you have to use Dynamic SQL Pivot.  While you may not want aggregration, the database doesn't know how to handle situations where the same date is listed more than once.  Since you know (or do you?) that each date is unique, you could just use min or max as it will have no impact  on the results, since each record is unique.

Comment: It sounds like a `pivot` was the right approach (the pivot would need to be dynamic most likely).  You'll need an aggregate function.  But if there is only one row being aggregated, that shouldn't be a problem.